# Why States in India don't have elections at a same time?

Tags: election, democracy, india

Andhra Pradesh & Telegana had elections in 2014. (In this elections, New **Prime Minister** was elected)

Tamil Nadu had elections in 2016.

UP, Goa & Bihar election going on now i.e 2017.

Why States in India don't have elections at a same time?

Comment: Why should they? The same applies to elections for the provincial legislatures in Canada and Australia and for elections in the länder in Germany.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Indian Express](http://indianexpress.com/article/india/india-news-india/election-commission-of-india-parliament-elections-state-assembly-election-clubbing-polls-modi-2840348/) published an article about this in June of 2016.

The article mentions the following barriers. I believe these came from a report by the election commission:

- There will additional expenses involved in purchasing more voting machines and hiring additional staff. Currently they need fewer devices and staff because they administer only some elections at one time.
- The terms of state assemblies are staggered by the Constitution. So the Constitution must be amended to allow a simultaneous election.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons as state by other users, because India has a large population and as you know is a democracy where there are many elections happened for MP, MLA, municipal corporations, gram panchayat etc.

Conducting simultaneous elections is a daunting task because elections involves many task like issuing voter id card for new electors, managing lists of candidate and electors, putting checks on behavior of candidates.

Main working force of ECI is teachers and same rank government official managing them from all over India at same time is a [challenge](http://www.hindustantimes.com/mumbai-news/teachers-want-exemption-from-duty-during-municipal-elections/story-4p3na89GqYXqeCrZdUVxJL.html).

And as other stated it is [costly](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/Election-Commission-2014-Lok-Sabha-elections-polls-expense/articleshow/30587202.cms) to conduct elections.

Answer (score -1):

The main Problem for conduction of election at same time is the presence of ballots ,presence of Election Commission Officials , Security at each Polling Booth is not possible at one time .